# RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'forecast'

Tags: python, rpy2

I tried to install `forecast` package in python using `rpy2`:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import r
fore = importr("forecast")
```

But it is giving some errors:

```
RRuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-07185d7e0d3a> in <module>
      1 from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
      2 from rpy2.robjects import r
----> 3 fore = importr("forecast")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2-2.9.4-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\rpy2\robjects\packages.py in importr(name, lib_loc, robject_translations, signature_translation, suppress_messages, on_conflict, symbol_r2python, symbol_check_after, data)
    451     if _package_has_namespace(rname, 
    452                               _system_file(package = rname)):
--> 453         env = _get_namespace(rname)
    454         version = _get_namespace_version(rname)[0]
    455         exported_names = set(_get_namespace_exports(rname))

RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'forecast'
```

Comment: Do you have forecast installed on your computer?

Comment: where should i install it?Is it in R studio? @Mike

Comment: yes in R try `install.packages('forecast')`

Comment: yes, I installed it but still, it gives the same error. Does python have an equivalent module or code for tsoutlier function of r?@Mike

Comment: interesting did you restart both python and R?

Comment: yeah but still it doesn't works.@Mike

Comment: Note that `rpy2` is not really supported on Windows. Compiled binaries and how to build them is kindly contributed by a very small number of Windows users (e.g., https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Beside that, latest rpy2 releases are no longer expected to work at all with windows... until Windows users make it work again, starting with https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/commits/315a7093bcf0b99b3a656dc15347557082c7a4fc

Answer (score 3):

I found the same error message when I tried to load another package that was not installed yet. 
For example, I tried to load a package named `forecast`. Here is my approach:

1. Try to open your R program, and try to install manually, by type `install.packages("forecast")` as well. Then, you can reload (restart) the python script, try to do the same thing (load the package `forecast`)
2. You can manually install from your python for any unresolved packages that you are willing to use/load. Here is my code:
   `rpy2.robjects.r('install.packages("forecast")')`

Or you can automate like this

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro

package_name = "forecast"

try:
    pkg = importr(package_name)
except:
    ro.r(f'install.packages("{package_name}")')
    pkg = importr(package_name)
pkg
```

Hope it helps